# springboot monogdb update nested document

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-update, nested-documents

Document Structure

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61e6e300f78f707b9c3ec32f"
  },
  "userId": "61d51daa0e09c2a97f11c81d",
  "services": [
    {
      "sId": "62036c3cde7ac3b60203bdb5",
      "status": 1,
      "permissionGroups": [
        {
          "pgId": "61e52858b6d31433bb7faf6c",
          "status": 1,
          "permissions": [
            {
              "pId": "61e3f5891e0b130b3a228ff0",
              "status": 1
            },
            {
              "pId": "61e4ec54974ad2600b58f2ad",
              "status": 1
            },
            {
              "pId": "61e4ec54974ad2600b58f2ae",
              "status": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "pgId": "61e8456e5b1359cb2b89888c",
          "status": 1,
          "permissions": [
            {
              "pId": "61e5086fd3af37389f1ba2a0",
              "status": 1
            },
            {
              "pId": "61e50870d3af37389f1ba2a1",
              "status": 1
            },
            {
              "pId": "61e52313f1a85a169f4f9afd",
              "status": 1
            },
            {
              "pId": "61e525c4f1a85a169f4f9b00",
              "status": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
   ]
  }
```

Im trying to update a field in the nested document (above mentioned) using mongo query in springboot. my purpose is to update the field called status inside permissions array. i know the query to update it using mongo shell, can someone help me convert the query to java or suggest me a way to do the same.

```
db.customer_service_details.update(
  {
    "userId": "61d51daa0e09c2a97f11c81d",
    "services": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "sId": "62036c3cde7ac3b60203bdb5","permissionGroups.pgId": "61e52858b6d31433bb7faf6c","permissionGroups.permissions.pId":"61e3f5891e0b130b3a228ff0"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": { "services.$[outer].permissionGroups.$[inner].permissions.$[inner3].status": "7899" }
  },
  {
    "arrayFilters": [{ "outer.sId": "62036c3cde7ac3b60203bdb5" },{ "inner.pgId": "61e52858b6d31433bb7faf6c" },{"inner3.pId":"61e3f5891e0b130b3a228ff0"}] 
    
    
  }
)
```

Comment: Here is a similar question with an answer: [Issue with update 2nd level nested array element using spring boot mongotemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66288099/issue-with-update-2nd-level-nested-array-element-using-spring-boot-mongotemplate).

Comment: And your question does not have a link or a picture that you're telling people to refer to

Comment: I managed to do the query in java, thanks for the responses.